# In a template how do you access an outer scope while inside of a "with" or "range" scope?

Tags: go, go-templates

When inside a `with` or `range`, the scope of `.` is changed. How do you access the calling scope?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
{{with .Inner}}
  Outer: {{$.OuterValue}}
  Inner: {{.InnerValue}}
{{end}}
```

`$` is documented in the [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) docs:

> When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

Answer (score 29):

You can save the calling scope with a variable:

```
{{ $save := . }}
{{ with .Inner }}
  Outer: {{ $save.OuterValue }}
  Inner: {{ .InnerValue }}
{{ end }}
```