# beego template value range executing "content" not a field of struct type

Tags: go, beego, go-templates

in my controller i set the following data:

```
c.Data["foos"] = foos
```

and

```
c.Data["user"] = user
```

So if I ask some property from user in the view, all fine.

```
{{if .user.IsSuperUser}}
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Username</th>
{{end}}
```

But in:

```
<tbody>
{{range $foo := .foos}}
   <tr>
   {{if .user.IsSuperUser}}
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
   {{end}}
...
```

> myBeego:template: foo/foos.tpl:56:46: executing "content" at
>   <.user.IsSuperUser>: user is not a field of struct type *models.Foo

How can I handle that?

Thanks for every help and happy Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this nice little link: [In a template how do you access an outer scope while inside of a "with" or "range" scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800204/in-a-template-how-do-you-access-an-outer-scope-while-inside-of-a-with-or-rang?rq=1)

```
{{with .Inner}}
  Outer: {{$.OuterValue}}
  Inner: {{.InnerValue}}
{{end}}
```

That's it. :)